# Can I get Operating System from the web browser?

Tags: javascript

**The Scenario**

I'm asking this question because I know from using Node.js you can use this code to pull user information from the operating system.

```
console.log(userInfo());
```

**Question**

Is there a way that you could get this information from a hosted website that's hosted on an Apache server?

Or, can JavaScript get this information outside of using Node.js?

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't make this exactly clear, I want specifically the user information not just the OS, so for example on windows you can have multiple user accounts i wanted the username for the current account. The current answer and duplication links all lead to getting the operating system information but not the currently logged in users name.

Comment: Yes, you can in window.navigator.appVersion

Comment: @DanteTheSmith that has been dropped from the standards.  From MDN:  "this feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time."

Comment: @Amy Goot to know, TY

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `ua-parser-js` to identify the OS in the browser

https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js

from the documentation

```
getOS()
returns { name: '', version: '' }
# Possible 'os.name'
AIX, Amiga OS, Android, Arch, Bada, BeOS, BlackBerry, CentOS, Chromium OS, Contiki,
Fedora, Firefox OS, FreeBSD, Debian, DragonFly, Gentoo, GNU, Haiku, Hurd, iOS, 
Joli, Linpus, Linux, Mac OS, Mageia, Mandriva, MeeGo, Minix, Mint, Morph OS, NetBSD, 
Nintendo, OpenBSD, OpenVMS, OS/2, Palm, PC-BSD, PCLinuxOS, Plan9, Playstation, QNX, RedHat, 
RIM Tablet OS, RISC OS, Sailfish, Series40, Slackware, Solaris, SUSE, Symbian, Tizen, 
Ubuntu, UNIX, VectorLinux, WebOS, Windows [Phone/Mobile], Zenwalk

# 'os.version' determined dynamically
```